# sharepoint 2010 how to create a webpart with a treeview?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I have sharepoint 2010 and visual studio 2010.

I want to create a webpart that will contain a tree view and it will show all files from a list or library (the path should be configurable in the web part settings).

The tree view should be compatible with folders.

Also I want it so that you can change the order of the items, so I want beside each item an up and down arrow button, then when clicked will change the order of the item, but this needs to affect the original list as well.

So I was thinking of having a column on the original list called orderby, then have it be sorted by that column. Then this web part can change the number of the item in the orderby column of the original list and then refresh the webpart to load the changes.

I don't know much on web part programming yet, but can anyone help me get started?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Sharepoint Solution in Visual Studio. The difference between a classic WebPart and a visual WebPart project is, that in the visual Webpart project you can add the control like a treview in design time to the desired webpart per drag and drop or via

That means, you need to create a webpart and put in your webpart the [ASP.Net Treeview](http://quickstarts.asp.net/quickstartv20/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/navigation/treeview.aspx). After that you need to [read the items of a list or library](https://jtheblog.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/retrieving-list-items-caml-queries-101/) and add the items to the treeview.

In case of folders you need to recursively loop through the folders.

I would start step by step. Read some good articles on creating simple WebParts, for example in MSDN, first. After that, look how to retrieve items and folders from libraries. After that look how to work with a ASP.Net TreeView. And last put all the elements together.

Answer (score -1):

A webpart essentially hosts an ascx control. If you can create a web control that does what you want, hosting it inside a webpart is not that big a deal.

First thing you will have to do is get a new SharePoint installation on your development box.

Next create a new Visual Webpart Project with Visual Studio 2010.